# detecting changes with ckeditor

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I've been googling around to find a solution but without any working solutions yet. I want to detect if the textarea has been changed. I'm using ckeditor so you can't check the textarea itself. I found something in the documentation but I couldn't get it to work for me.

Did someone ever tried to do this before and is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some research and a lot of googling a found a suitable method.

```
var content_editor = CKEDITOR.instances['content'];

content_editor.on( 'key', function() {
    change_page = true;
});
```

Comment: that does not take into account the case when text inside textarea is changed by editor commands (like undo/redo for e.g)

Comment: @OviC Agreed. I would make a separate listener for those. Most likely CKeditor has a callback for it.

Answer (score 4):

I used the jquery ckeditor method.

Here is the html:

```
<textarea id="txtMessage" class="editor" maxlength="500"></textarea>
```

and here is the javascript:

```
try {
        var config =
            {
                height: 180,
                width: 515,
                linkShowAdvancedTab: false,
                scayt_autoStartup: true,
                enterMode: Number(2),
                toolbar_Full: [['Styles', 'Bold', 'Italic', 
                                              'Underline', 'SpellChecker', 'Scayt', 
                                              '-', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList'],
                      ['Link', 'Unlink'], ['Undo', 'Redo', '-', 'SelectAll']]

            };

        $('textarea.editor').ckeditor(config);
        CKEDITOR.instances["txtMessage"].on("instanceReady", InstanceReadyEvent);

    }
    catch (err) {
        alert('Error loading ck editor: ' + err);
    }

    function InstanceReadyEvent() {
        this.document.on("keyup", function () {

            var yourText = CKEDITOR.instances["txtMessage"].getData();
        });
    }
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

There is a checkDirty() function that you could "poll".  Otherwise look at the SCAYT plugin, I think they monitor keystrokes.

But I do not know of a "public" event that fires,  check out; 
   CKEDITOR.dom.event (DOM event handler)
   CKEDITOR.event  (internal event handler)

Answer (score 0):

(old post, but google bring me here)

From the [official website](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_savedata.html#observing-changes-in-ckeditor), you have :

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );

// The "change" event is fired whenever a change is made in the editor.
editor.on( 'change', function( evt ) {
    // getData() returns CKEditor's HTML content.
    console.log( 'Total bytes: ' + evt.editor.getData().length );
});
```