# changing .net textbox value problem

Tags: jquery, .net

here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var val1 = $("#Content_txtYorum").val();

    function checkChanges() {
        var val2 = $("#Content_txtYorum").val();
        console.log(val1 + " " + val2);  // for test
        if (val1 != val2)
            alert($("#Content_txtYorum").val());
        setTimeout(function () 
        {
            checkChanges();
        }, 3000);

    }

    checkChanges();
});
```

i try to write my textChange event.. but variable val2 never changes when i write something to textbox.
what is the problem ?

thanks..

Comment: The problem is that we have no idea how you expect the code to behave.  You need to be more clear when asking questions or you will get nowhere!

Comment: and maybe, mention things like that your using cke editor at the begining, instead of after i've come up with 3 different solutions that solve 3 different problems that you've changed the question to being.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just add a handler to the .change()  event of your text box!

```
$('#Content_txtYorum').change(function(){
   alert( $('#Content_txtYorum').val());

});
```

check out the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/4QHZ7/

EDIT:  as per your comment, keyup should work for you:

```
$('#Content_txtYorum').keyup(function(){
   alert( $('#Content_txtYorum').val());

});
```

the fiddle is updated as well
http://jsfiddle.net/4QHZ7/1/

EDIT:  as per your new comment, keyup should work for you:

```
$('.ClassOnYourDoTNetFields').keyup(function(){
   alert( $(this).val());

});
```

EDIT:  now that you've changed the question entirely... here's another answer:

check out this question of stack overflow:  it gives 2 different possible solutions:

[detecting changes with ckeditor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230839/detecting-changes-with-ckeditor)

Comment: yes but change() function works in blur event. i need let it works as soon as when i write.

Comment: it works for html inputs.. but on.net textbox its not work in spite of i use clientID.

Comment: oooh right, forgot that detail,  give your textboxes that you want to use this on a common class, and then use a class selector, i'll update the answer

Comment: Patricia thanks this works.. But i have another problem, my textbox is for CKEditor so keyup() not work for this textbox..i tried normal textbox, it was work  with class attr.

Comment: oh... i see, you probably should have mentioned that at the beginning.... that changes EVERYTHING

Comment: yess.. the solution works for me.. thank you very much Patrica.

Comment: excellent!  in the future, try to provide all these kind of details in the question :)